# traefik: how can I route a static file from / to one of the containers, in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, routes, docker-compose, traefik, static-files

I have a specific service inside docker-compose.yml called 'fastapi', which is based on the fastAPI python package.

```
      fastapi:
        image: fastapi
        labels:
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/fastapi"
          - traefik.port=5000
        volumes:
          - ./fastapi:/app
          - ./data:/data
```

traefik route to the the fastapi through **localhost/fastapi**.

However: There is an internal call to **openapi.json** where the server search for in /openapi.json, and get a "404 page not found" error.
How can I route static files from **localhost/openapi.json** to **localhost/fastapi/openapi.json**.

I tried this rule, **but it does not work!**

```
labels:
   - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefixStrip:/fastapi,Path:/openapi.json"
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I missed the obvious answer from the FastAPI documentation:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sub-applications-proxy/

```
FastAPI(openapi_prefix="/subapi")
```